# How can I properly display terminal output on a Flask-based website?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

In a Flask application, I utilize the subprocess module to run a command in a shell on a Linux-based device. I send the command's output as a field in the HTTP response, and the browser displays it in an HTML template that I've written. When I display the output, it looks weirdly spaced and just has an odd format in general. How can I preserve the spacing/format of the output when displaying it using an HTML file? Is it possible to do this in a way where the output that is displayed looks visually pleasing, with a professional-looking style/font?

Comment: Did you try using <pre>{shell output}</pre>? This should keep newline and spacing. It might be helpful if you add some code of your HTML template so that users can see what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your output in preformatted tags, i.e.

<pre>

shell output
goes here
</pre>

```
shell output
goes here
```

That tells the browser to use fixed pitch font and not to rewrap it.

Comment: This is correct!